# How to disable Moya_Logger from Moya framework

Tags: swift, moya

I am using [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) framework as network layer for the Alamofire and i am interested in if it is possible to switch off Moa_Logger that logging all responses and request from my application?

I am trying to configure plugin but still i need some help.

`[NetworkLoggerPlugin(verbose: false, responseDataFormatter: JSONResponseDataFormatter)]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just not include anything into plugins:

```
var provider = RxMoyaProvider<MyAPI>()
```